# Convert MySQL variable query to SQLite query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a query in MySQL like below. I want to convert this query into SQLite query but SQLite does not support variable. How can I do this in SQlite?

```
SELECT trx_date,@balance opening, net_bill, due, @balance := @balance + net_bill - due closing
FROM transactions, (SELECT @balance := 0) variable
WHERE trx_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-04' ORDER BY trx_date;
```

Comment: You should have tagged your original question as SQLite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Since the version of SQLite in use is too early to support window functions, another way to do this is to `LEFT JOIN` the `transactions` table to itself requiring the `id` value in the joined table to be lower. The `due` and `bill` values from the joined table can then be summed to get the `opening` and `closing` values:

```
SELECT t1.trx_date,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.bill)-SUM(t2.due), 0) AS opening,
       t1.bill,
       t1.due,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.bill)-SUM(t2.due), 0) + t1.bill - t1.due AS closing
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2 ON t2.id < t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
trx_date    bill    due     opening     closing
2020-03-01  100     10      0           90
2020-03-02  50      20      90          120
2020-03-02  100     0       120         220
2020-03-03  200     20      220         400
2020-03-04  110     10      400         500
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ESdoyQnY5GwiSHGET3HPx/1)

Note that this query will run on MySQL as well.

**Original Answer**

SQLite supports window functions, which makes this query a lot easier:

```
SELECT trx_date,
       COALESCE(SUM(bill-due) OVER (ORDER BY trx_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS opening,
       bill,
       due,
       SUM(bill-due) OVER (ORDER BY trx_date) AS closing
FROM transactions
```

Output:

```
trx_date    opening     bill    due     closing
2020-03-01  0           100     10      90
2020-03-02  90          50      20      220
2020-03-02  120         100     0       220
2020-03-03  220         200     20      400
2020-03-04  400         110     10      500
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xx2cjamKE1SpKAXyMrDXAY/1)

Note that when you have multiple transactions on a given `trx_date` you will get the same `closing` value for all of them. This can be worked around if you have another ordering column which has unique values. See for example this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xx2cjamKE1SpKAXyMrDXAY/2) which uses an `id` column.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My SQLite version with PHP is 3.20 so that window functions not working according to your query.

Comment: @Akashkhan that's unfortunate! Does the table have an `id` column of some form (a unique, increasing value)?

Comment: Yes, it has an id auto-increment column.

Comment: @Akashkhan see my edit. I've added a query which will work on both SQLite and MySQL which doesn't require window functions.